# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate: Code completion for JS included via simple script tag

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, intellij-idea-2016

I manage to get perfect code completion when working with npm and ES6 modules – but **how do I get code completion when I just have a single HTML with the JS included via script tag**?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>
    d3.select("body") // Unresolved variable or type d3
</script>
</body>
```

I tried adding D3 as a library (Project Settings > Libraries) – to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this WebStorm blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/) to be very helpful. In summary:

- `<script>` tags are just used by the browser; they don't influence the IDE's behavior regarding code completion/navigation/error highlighting/etc.
- Code completion/navigation/error highlighting/etc is determined by JS libraries (*Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries*)
- These libraries can be [configured manually](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-javascript-libraries.html), or can be generated via a quick fix: Using the `<script src="..."></script>` attribute, select the https link, and invoke "Download library". Illustrated by this screenshot presented in the blog:

[image]

This fixes my "Unresolved variable or type d3" problem. IntelliJ IDEA still seems to get confused about chained statements which span across multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`

Make the mouse hover over "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js".
Click “Download library”.

……

Wait a minute, then it's OK.